# Property of type Dictionary in Swift class not visible to Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, dictionary, xcode6

I have a persisting problem with using a Swift class in Objective-C code:

The Swift class looks as follows:

```
@objc class TestClass {
    private (set) var key:  UInt64
    private (set) var dict: [UInt64 : Double]! = [:]

    init(key: UInt64, value: Double) {
        self.key = key
        self.dict[key] = value
    }
}
```

When I try to use in Objective-C with `test.dict` the compiler (in Xcode 6.1.1) marks an error `Property 'dict' not found on object of type 'TestClass'`.

The odd thing is that the generated `MyProject-Swift.h` refers to `key` but not to `dict`. Here is the relevant excerpt:

```
@interface TestClass
@property (nonatomic, readonly) uint64_t key;
- (instancetype)initWithKey:(uint64_t)key value:(double)value OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

This is true to an older version (I've added `dict` after `key`), but no longer reflects the definition in Swift. However, the problem does not seem to be related to the order of build steps for if I add a property `private (set) var key2: UInt64` it shows up in `MyProject-Swift.h`. Cleaning and rebuilding the project does not help (neither does restarting Xcode).

What is wrong with my code and bridging between Objective-C and Swift in this instance? Could it be because `dict` is defined as a Swift (not Objective-C nor `@objc`) dictionary? If so, how can I refactor the code to make progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your dictionary uses types that are not mappable to Objective-C.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_49) says:

> When you cast [...] from a Swift dictionary to an NSDictionary object
>   the keys and values must be instances of a class or bridgeable to an
>   instance of a class.

You need a declaration like:

```
private (set) var dict: [NSNumber: NSNumber]! = [:]
```

Then your dictionary property will appear in the bridging header.

Comment: Can you please add an exact link to the cited documentation then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: What does `private` here mean?

Comment: @Zaph It gives the setter a lower access level (`private`) than the getter (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)).

Comment: I've updated my answer and inserted a link to the documentation.